# How to echo content to each file in subfolders in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, find, batch-processing

I've a directory structure like this:

```
/posts
|
|
posts/page1 -- index.html
posts/page2 -- index.html
posts/page{3..100} -- index.html
```

I've figured out how to create 100 different `page#` directories, and I've touched `index.html` to each of them. However, I need to echo some basic HTML to each of the `index.html` files in each of the `page#` directories.

```
 for f in `find . -type d`; do echo "hello" >> f; done
```

but all that does is echo 100 `hello`s to a file named `f`

```
 for f in `find . -type d`; do echo "hello"; done
```

simply echos `hello` 100 times.

and

```
for f in `find . -type d`; do echo "hello" >> index.html; done
```

just echos `hello` 100 times within `posts/index.html`

Anyway, I'm at a loss how to do this. How would I do this without having to *manually* do it? Theoretically I could open each folder in Sublime and copy the HTML then `Ctrl+V + Ctrl+S + Ctrl+W` for each instance, but there's gotta be a much easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `$f` to refer the items in your `find` result, instead of `f`. And also, include `/index.html` to the path:

```
for f in $(find . -type d); do echo "hello" >> $f/index.html; done
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In your current code you were redirecting to the constant `f`, while you want to refer to the variable name `$f`. That is the reason of using `$f` instead of `f`.

Comment: Ah, spot on. Thank you fedorqui! 
I'll select you as the right answer as soon as I am allowed to. Thanks again.

- Eric

Answer (score 1):

```
> for f in `find . -type d`; do echo "hello" >> index.html; done
```

Command substitution is subject to word splitting and pathname expansion (globbing).  This fails when filenames contain spaces (and/or wildcards).  Either set IFS to a single newline (IFS=$'\n') and disable pathname expansion (set -f) (N.B. this will still fail if filenames contain newlines) or use find's -exec:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'for dir in "$@" ; do echo "hello" >> "$dir/index.html" ; done' sh {} +
```